# Using OleDb cannot insert into database

Tags: sql, ms-access

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''1'）'.

This is my code

```
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= Database1.mdb;")
Dim command As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Student_Enquiry (StudentID,Email,Receiver,Comment) VALUES('" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + ComboBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox4.Text + "'）", connection)

command.Connection.Open()
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
command.Connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the final closing parenthesis in the insert statement actually isn't a normal Right Parenthesis; it is a different character.

You used `）` - "Fullwidth Right Parenthesis", U+FF09
instead of `)` - "Right Parenthesis", U+0029, ASCII 0x29

Compare the the invalid and the valid: `）` != `)`

Use this instead:

```
Dim command As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Student_Enquiry (StudentID,Email,Receiver,Comment) VALUES('" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + ComboBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox4.Text + "')", connection)
```

Also, you really shouldn't inject values into the query but rather use parametrized queries to avoid issues with potential [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) etcetera. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows you how to do this.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for the edit, I was wondering what the invalid character actually was; it evaluated as ascii 41 in MSSQL just as a normal right parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for you all help me! 
） != )   <<< like this error also can found it. PRO! I love you all !

Comment: But one more question...   how about the update code?
Is it UPDATE Student_Enquiry something like this??

Comment: @meili Yes. The basic syntax for update is `update your_table set your_column = new_value`.

Comment: @jpw currently my system need to if i edit my studentID then will update the studentID....     i'm just code :
UPDATE Student_Information SET StudentID='"+Textbox1.text+"' WHERE StudentID = ""  
Am i correct?

Comment: @meili It looks correct if your intention is to change the StudentID for rows where the StudenID is an empty string.

Comment: @jpw   May i ask one more question. About the Count function. I posted. 
Can you help me to see the problem? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967055/in-oledb-am-i-code-like-this-correct-for-count-in-vb

Comment: @meili I don't know vb or oledb well enough to answer, sorry. The sql looks correct though.