# OLEDB - select Count not working

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Find below what I've done so far, but unfortunately it's not working.

```
       Private BS as New BindingSource
       Dim ds As New DataSet
     ' Make the Connection
       Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = Database1.mdb")
       con.Open()
       Dim Sql = "SELECT COUNT ([Eventname]) FROM Eventproposal"
       Dim da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, con)
       da.Fill(ds, "Eventproposal")
     ' Set the Binding Source
      bs.DataSource = ds.Tables("Eventproposal")
     con.Close()
 End Using
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "")
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on execution? what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things, you should end all SQL Commands to MS Access with `;`

```
Dim Sql = "SELECT COUNT ([Eventname]) FROM Eventproposal;"
```

And you did not name your column which will give you an error when you attempt to access it by name.

```
Dim Sql = "SELECT COUNT ([Eventname]) AS Eventname FROM Eventproposal;"
```

I believe it will give it a name but not what your thinking. Lastly, when you do your binding, you will have to reference the name of the field in the table.

```
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Eventname")
```

Comment: I don't think the semicolon is necessary unless you need to specifically terminate the line.  I know I've never used it for any OleDB queries and it's never been an issue.